# JavaScript RegExp from a string then running .test() doesn't seem to work

Tags: javascript, regex

I thought that by instantiating a pattern = new RegExp() and passing a string then using .test(value) would be the same as using /^...$/.test(value), but they don't appear to be equal as using RegExp and passing a string fails each time.  Is this not correct? On [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions) it seems to say that this should work.

SHOULD ALL FAIL AND THEY DO

```
var str = "7D>";
var res = /^[A-Za-z0-9\d=!\-@._*]*$/.test(str);
console.log(res); // false which is correct

var patt = /^[A-Za-z0-9\d=!\-@._*]*$/;
var res = patt.test(str);
console.log(res); // false which is correct

var patt = new RegExp("/^[A-Za-z0-9\d=!\-@._*]*$/");
var res = patt.test(str);
console.log(res); // false which is correct, but suspicious based on follow results
```

SHOULD ALL PASS AND THEY DON'T

```
var str = "7D";
var res = /^[A-Za-z0-9\d=!\-@._*]*$/.test(str);
console.log(res); // true which is correct

var patt = /^[A-Za-z0-9\d=!\-@._*]*$/;
var res = patt.test(str);
console.log(res); // true which is correct
```

BUT BOTH THESE ATTEMPTS FAIL WHEN THEY SHOULD PASS

```
var patt = new RegExp("/^[A-Za-z0-9\d=!\-@._*]*$/");
var res = patt.test(str);
console.log(res); // false which is NOT correct

var patt = new RegExp("^[A-Za-z0-9\d=!\-@._*]*$");
var res = patt.test(str);
console.log(res); // ALSO false which is NOT correct
```

Comment: You have to escape the `\-` in the string you pass to `new RegExp` as `\\-`. Otherwise, put the `-` at the end of the character set.

Comment: @torazaburo: *Beginning*, not end. *Edit:* Hey, interesting, both work. Useful to know. At least one rex engine I used (not JavaScript) took `-` at the end to mean no upper bound on the character class.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder *beginning **or** end*?

Comment: @torazaburo: Yup, apparently.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Two things:

1. You don't include the `/` when using a string
2. You **do** have to escape backslashes (as always, in a string literal)

So this:

```
var patt = new RegExp("/^[A-Za-z0-9\d=!\-@._*]*$/");
```

should be

```
var patt = new RegExp("^[A-Za-z0-9\\d=!\\-@._*]*$");
//                    ^           ^^   ^^        ^
```

If you had flags, you'd include them as a second string argument:

```
var patt = new RegExp("^[a-z\\d=!\\-@._*]*$", "i");
```

---

Side note:

`\d` means "digit" which is defined in the spec as `0-9`, so having `0-9` *and* `\d` in the character class is redundant